# DOJO xhrGet how to use returned json object?

Tags: ajax, dojo

How can I access the data returned from the xhrGet outside of the get itself? Firebug shows that the "json" object has an array called results, which stores the json Object from the response, but when I try to access it it is null. So: how do I access the received data on the last code line?

```
var json = dojo.xhrGet({
    url :'/disease_web/graphMlDownload/getEdgeInformation/', handleAs:"json",content : {  edgeid : edgeId, graphname:this._canvas.path},
    load:function(response){
        return response;
    }
});
console.log(json.ioArgs);
console.log(json.results);
```

Answer (score 3):

By default dojo.xhrGet is called asynchronously, so console.log(json.results) is null because it's run just after dojo.xhrGet, but before response comes from server.

```
var xhrGet = dojo.xhrGet({
        url: "/some_rul",
        handleAs: "json",
        handle: function(response) {
            console.info(2,'response',response);                
            console.info(3,'xhrGet.results[0]',xhrGet.results[0]);
        }
 });
 console.info(1,xhrGet.hasOwnProperty('results'));
```

The result is:

1 false

2 response - ['some data from server']

3 xhrGet.results[0] - same data as in 'response' accessed via xhrGet

Answer (score 0):

<s>The simplest way to access your retrieved JSON data is to assign it to a document-level variable within the xhrGet load function:</s>

```
var fetchedData = null;

function parseResponse() { /* do something meaningful */ }

dojo.xhrGet({
  url: "{{dataUrl}}dojo/LICENSE",
  handleAs: "json",
  preventCache: true,
  load: function(response){
    // save for later
    window.fetchedData = response;

    // do whatever processing we want with the returned data
    parseResponse();
  },
  error: function(error){
    alert("Couldn't fetch your data: " + error);
  }
});
```

Yeah, no. I've since learned a much better way, and forgot to come back and fix this answer, so it deserves the downvotes it's accrued.

The *proper* way to deal with data fetched from dojo.xhrGet, jQuery.ajax, or any other asynchronous data fetch is to write a function to process its results, and pass it to xhrGet as the **load** argument, like so:

```
var request = dojo.xhrGet({ url :'/disease_web/graphMlDownload/getEdgeInformation/',
    handleAs: "json",
    content : {edgeid : edgeId, graphname:this._canvas.path},
    load: doSomethingWithMyEdges
});
function doSomethingWithMyEdges(json_results) {
    console.log(json_results);
}
```

Comment: I realize this is an old answer, but I figured I'd explain why this is a bad idea:  How do you know when there's actually a value ready?!  XHR is non-blocking which means window.fetchedData will be undefined until the XHR returns.  There is only race-condition hell beyond this approach!

Comment: No, you're absolutely right. I answered this before I really grokked how to do things the "right" way.

Comment: Rewritten with a better answer.