# Dojo Get data from server and store in a variable using xhrGet

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have the following function:

```
loadMsgBody: function (id) {
    return dojo.xhrGet({
        url: "myurl",
        handleAs: "text",
        content: {
            id: id
        },
        load: function (response) {
            return response;
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}
```

And calling it:

```
var text = "";
this.loadMsgBody(this.msgId).then(function (response) {
    text = response;
});
```

Now I expect to get the return value of the function but instead I am getting an empty value for text. However, in Firebug I do see the response from the server with the correct value. I've searched and found these links : [DOJO xhrGet how to use returned json object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044489/dojo-xhrget-how-to-use-returned-json-object)
and:
[Using hitch / deferred with an xhrGet request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157432/using-hitch-deferred-with-an-xhrget-request)
But I still can't get and store the data with the above code. I don't want to do the manipulation inside the xhrGet call, I want to retrieve the data and use as it will be used multiple times.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: What do you get in Firebug when you call `var myData = this.loadMsgBody(this.msgId);`? And can you set a breakpoint in your function callback for `then` and note what `text` is being assigned?

Comment: I get `[object Object]`. But in firebug I see the response with the expected data from the server.

Comment: What is the value of `response` in the `load` callback? It looks like some object is being converted into a string, and possibly this is not what you want.

Comment: I'm not sure you should actually return anything from `load`.

Comment: Inside the load callback the data is as expected.

Comment: Try something like `var myData = this.loadMsgBody(this.msgId).load();`. Just a hunch, since `load` returns an object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
loadMsgBody: function (id, callback) {
    return dojo.xhrGet({
        url: "myurl",
        handleAs: "text",
        content: {
            id: id
        },
        load: function (response) {
            callback.apply(null,[response]);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Then:

```
var text = "";
this.loadMsgBody(this.msgId, function (response) {
    text = response;
    console.log("text:",text);  // this will show your return data

});

 console.log("text:",text);  // this will show empty data because ajax call is asynchrize, at this time , data not return yet.

 setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("text:",text);  // this will show your return data again because ajax call should have finished after 30000 ms 
 },30000)
```

Comment: This returns empty data for text but response is ok with expected data.

Comment: I don't know where you use your 'text' variable? you need make sure that you use it after asynchorize ajax get data back, see my update code.

Comment: That is the purpose of use then but even that doesn't work with assigning value. You can get the value inside the then function but even if you assign it, you get empty data.

Comment: I have a feeling that you might misunderstanding "then", even you use then, it is still async. I add more in code to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Dojo's XHR methods return instances of the class [dojo/Deferred](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/Deferred.html), because they are asynchronous.  What this means is that the functions returns before the value of the response is available.  In order to work with the results of the asynchronous response you need to wait for it to return.  Dojo exposes this using a uniform API, Deferreds.  Instances of the `dojo/Deferred` class have a method `then`.  The `then` method takes a function as a parameter.  That function will execute once the Deferred have been resolved (in this case, when the request has completed).

```
var deferred = loadMsgBody();
deferred.then(function(response){
  //work with response
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing your `load` function to evoke your `callback` function:

```
loadMsgBody: function (id, callback) {
    return dojo.xhrGet({
        url: "myurl",
        handleAs: "text",
        content: {
            id: id
        },
        load: function (response) {
            if(callback) {
                callback(response);
            }
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}
```